# Проблемы производительности в браузере сафари на маке

Tags: вёрстка, производительность, mac

Всем привет!

Попался сложный макет, с кучей графики и крутилок вертелок. Вообщем тесты на на маке показали плачевный результат в виде дерганья скрола(только на маке), и проседание фпс. Покурил форумы нашел проблему с бекграундом фиксированным, исправил ее, но сайт не стал прокручиваться легче. Помогите советом куда копать, впервые сталкивааюсь с тем, что браузер не может прокрутить сайт.

вот пациент - [тут](http://test.hell-tech.ru/)

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Comment: Да, можно. В соседнем посте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Явный перебор анимаций и эффектов. Даже на `iMac Core i7 / 64GB RAM` ужасно лагает. Дело не только в методах, а и в переборе анимированных элементов и их количестве. Браузер не успевает даже на таком железе нормально обрабатывать обрисовку.

По `fixed background`, вы правильно заметили. Как минимум это тоже влияет на FPS. А также смотрите в сторону видео + JS/CSS анимаций.

**Что больше всего есть CPU?**

- Видео на фоне
- Паралакс эффекты
- Цикличные CSS анимации по типу box-shadow/text-shadow
- При скроллинге сайта сразу же подгружаются элементы, которые также
  анимируются, без каких либо задержек

Comment: то есть выход только в том чтобы отключить анимацию? тут столько же анимации но крутится вполне себе нормально [ссылка](http://dega-clinic.com/landing/yvelichenie_grudi_za_175), может есть способы компромисса?

Comment: На примере, что вы дали, явно нет столько анимаций. Там нет ни видео на фоне, ни постоянных свечений (описал выше про css text-shadow animation), ни паралакс эффектов, ни постоянных линейных эффектов по бокам (как у вас). Там только при скроллинге 1 анимация считайте. Анимация появления. У вас же, если грубо, то где-то в 4-5 раза больше.

Comment: даже не знаю что делать, по сути нужно как то оптимизировать, так как анимация часть тз

Comment: Попытаться обяснить клиенту, что все это конечно круто, но это явный перебор. И люди любят clean design и минимум сложностей. Такая нагрузка не только на CPU, но и на человека влияет и просто хочеться уйти побыстрее, что сказать там об "информации" :)

Comment: спасибо за советы! я конечно предполагал что проблема в этом, но думал мало ли есть волшебная кнопка, которая устраняет тормоза, как например, я на одном проекте заменил анимацию по позиции на трансформ по позиции - прирост колоссальный